# Which tables can i share in multilingual multi-site installation?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, multi-sites

I have a multi-site installation with different databases. I've shared i18n_; language; locale_ tables. On the main installation several languages work just fine.
But on the others sites which i am trying to use also with multilingual settings i can't get language switcher appear whatever i try. They don't want to use prefix between nodes. Translated nodes are connected but there's no way to switch between them.
Please could you give advice which tables am i able to use to have shared translations without problems?

Comment: Well the only thing i`ve managed to is completely delete all modules connected to multilingual site and reinstalled them. I`ve tried to share tables locale after that which caused problems. So as i see you can only import/export translations manually to each of the sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood you almost cant use common tables on multi-site installation - i`ve been checking them one by one. First i configured all of sites - only the main site (from which tables were shared) could switch languages and translate nodes. On the others there were no switcher showing and translated nodes were not linking.

Maybe you can some, but still you got to have everything identical (starting from content types and endind with nodes)

Maybe i am wrong.